# How to click on next class name?

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver, arraylist

I have same class `<a class="row-title">` property up to 21 web element.
I am able to fetch all 21 elements using the get text method but I want to perform an operation like this.

1. first I have to click on XPath `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-posts-presentation']/a/div[3]"));`
2. then i want to click on `<a class="row-title">` first class name
3. step 3 i also wants to click on xpath `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='publish']")).click();`
4. then I have to again click on the same XPath which is in step1 and then click on second class name not first one and again click on XPath which is in 3 step3
5. so I want to iterate this up to 21 class name.

   ```
   Test(priority = 2)
   public void myfsk1(){ 

       driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-posts-presentation']/a/div[3]")).click();
       List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("row-title"));
       System.out.println(elements.size());

       for (int i=1;i<=elements.size()-1;i++)
       {
           System.out.println(elements.get(i).getText());
           Reporter.log(elements.get(i).getText());

       }
   ```

Comment: Please simplify your problem statement, it is very hard to understand your problem now. And the code you have shared, does not try to perform any of those click events in problem statement, try that code and then share the error if you face any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't forget to add some assertions to check if it was really clicked, now this test just clicks some links but checks nothing.
Also you have to add expected conditions to avoid clicking not loaded elements.

```
    Test(priority = 2)
    public void myfsk1 () {
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("row-title"));
        int listSize = elements.size();
        System.out.println(listSize);
        WebElement innerElement;

        for (int i = 1; i < listSize; i++) {
            driver.findElement(By.id("menu-posts-presentation"))
                  .findElement(By.xpath("./a/div[3]"))
                  .click();

            // Search again due to page refresh
            elements = driver.findElements(By.className("row-title"));
            innerElement = elements.get(i);

            System.out.println(innerElement.getText());
            Reporter.log(innerElement.getText());
            innerElement.click()

            driver.findElement(By.id("publish").click;
        }
    }
```

Comment: when i clicks on `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-posts-presentation']/a/div[3]")).click();` it open page of that class name and when click on first class name it open and then i wants to click on this x path `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='publish']")).click(); `, after that i have again click on first x path which gives me list of class name. these 3 elements are not in same page.

Comment: You didn't mentioned that.
So every click refreshes page, isn't?